# Function behaves strangely after first onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type = "text" id = "pick"> <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "guessWord()">
```

That runs my js function which works fine (with unrelated hiccups) on the first call. But if I change my text and submit it again without reloading my initial if/else statement behaves incorrectly. Specifically, the if/else is supposed to check if the user inputted word is in an array. It works properly on the first call, but after that it jumps to the else block even when it shouldn't.

Here is the js (apologies in advance for including the whole function, I'm just usually asked to include more code than I initially do):

```
function guessWord() {

  var comWords, match, compWord =  "";
  var possWords = dictFive;
  var firstFive = ["vibex", "fjord", "nymph", "waltz", "gucks"]; // note: right now choosing any of these words results in unexpected behavior -- either it doesn't accept them or it freezes.
  var inputWord = document.getElementById("pick").value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');

  if (possWords.includes(inputWord)) { // checks to see if the user inputted word is in our dictionary.i f not, requests a different word.

    // start game loop:

    // in order to try and get as much information as possible in the first few turns I start by guessing the five words in firstFive[]: vibex, fjord, nymph, waltz, gucks. together, these words give us information about 25 letters.

    for (let d = 0; d < inputWord.length; d++) { // this loop will run for the length of the inputted word, making it scaleable so in the future the program could accept shorter or longer words. within the current scope it will always be 5.

      compWord = firstFive[d]; // the computers word will loop through each word in firstFive[].

      if (inputWord === compWord) { // if the word matches the user inputted word:

        document.getElementById("otpt").innerHTML = "Your word was: " + firstFive[d] + ". I guessed it in " + (d + 1) + " turns.";
        return;

      } else { // if the word is not the user inputted word, then:

        comWords = (inputWord + compWord).split('').sort().join(''); // we combine the users word with the comps word and sort them by character.
        match = comWords.length - comWords.replace(/(\w)\1+/g, '$1').length; // match produces a numerical value for how many letters matched between both words.

        for (let e = 0; e < possWords.length; e++) { // loop to cycle through our dictionary.

          for (let f = 0; f < inputWord.length; f++) { // loop to cycle through all the different match options.

            if (match === 0) { // if there are no matches we can:

              if (possWords[e].includes(firstFive[f])) { // go through the dict and get rid of every word that has letters in common with the word.

                possWords.splice(e, 1);

              }

            } else if (match === f) { // if there's at least one letter in common:

              comWords = (possWords[e] + compWord).split('').sort().join(''); // as we cycle through the dict, pick each available word, combine and sort with the chosen word,
              var matchFive = comWords.length - comWords.replace(/(\w)\1+/g, '$1').length; // and then find how many letters match.

              if (matchFive != match) { // any words in dict that have a different match value can be deleted.

                possWords.splice(e, 1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // once we've worked through the words in firstFive[] we start guessing randomly.

    for (let a = 0; a < possWords.length; a++) { // the loop max is set to the length of the array because that's the maximum amount of time the guessing can take.

      compWord = possWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * possWords.length)]; // choose a random word.

      if (compWord === inputWord) { // check if the random word is the inputted word. if it is:

        document.getElementById("otpt").innerHTML = "Your word was: " + compWord + ". I guessed it in " + (a + 5) +  " turns. I had " + possWords.length + " remaining words that were possible matches.";
        return;

      } else { // while the word still isn't correct:

        comWords = (compWord + inputWord).split('').sort().join(''); // again, we join and sort it.
        match = comWords.length - comWords.replace(/(\w)\1+/g, '$1'); // find its match value.

        for (let c = 0; c < inputWord.length; c++) { // loop through inputted word's length to check all letters.

          if (match === 0) { // again, no matches we can safely delete all words with those letters.

            if (possWords.includes(compWord[c])) {
              possWords.splice(c, 1);

            }

          } else if (match === c) { // if match is higher than 0:

            for (let g = 0; g < possWords.length; g++) {

              comWords = (possWords[g]+ compWord).split('').sort().join('');
              matchAll = comWords.length - comWords.replace(/(\w)\1+/g, '$1');

              if (match != matchAll) {

                possWords.splice(g, 1);

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

      } else { // If the user inputted word was not in our dictionary, requests a different word:

    document.getElementById("otpt").innerHTML = "Please choose a different word.";

      }
    }
```

(For context, dictFive is an array located on a separate file.) The code is trying to guess the user inputted word by checking how many letters match and then splicing out words from the master array if they can't match, so the array possWords starts with about 2500 words and gets narrowed down to a few hundred by the end of the function. As far as I can tell, the function should be resetting the vars properly every time it's called, though, but I'm guessing it isn't for some reason?

Comment: Further testing confirms that the array which should have 2500 words stays sliced on each call, which is confusing to me because each function should start the array equal to a separate array that's not being touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dictFive` array is being `splice`d each time the function is called.

When you set `possWords = dictFive`, and then splice `possWords` later, you're also splicing `dictFive` because both variables refer to the same array. Then, the second time the function is run, `dictFive` is still in its spliced state. Instead of setting `possWords = dictFive`, try making a copy of the array. That way, you'll splice the copy without affecting the original, `dictFive`. You can clone an array by `possWords = dictFive.slice()`.

```
var dictFive = [0,1,2,3,4]; // Just an example of whatever dictFive might be
var possWords = dictFive; // This makes possWords refer to the same thing as dictFive
possWords.splice(0, 1); // Splicing the array at whatever point
possWords // [1,2,3,4] because the 0th element was spliced out
dictFive // also [1,2,3,4] because both dictFive and possWords are the same array
```

compare that to

```
var dictFive = [0,1,2,3,4];
var possWords = dictFive.slice(); // This makes a copy of the array instead of referencing the original dictFive
possWords.splice(0, 1);
possWords // [1,2,3,4];
dictFive // Now, this array is still [0,1,2,3,4] because only the possWords array was spliced. dictFive wasn't affected.
```